# Plotting multiple xy pairs in Gnuplot from file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data series that I'm trying to plot in Gnuplot of the format:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 ... xn, yn
```

Where every two adjacent columns represent an xy pair. I'm looking for a way to plot each of these xy pairs as separate lines using a single (concise-ish) command in Gnuplot, rather than trying a command like this:

```
plot "file" u 1:2 w l, "file" u 3:4 w l
```

...and so on.

Comment: Seems like something from [Dr.Kawano's gnuplot FAQ](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html), but the original link is down, so either use [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20121016162331/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html) or [this](http://security.riit.tsinghua.edu.cn/~bhyang/ref/gnuplot/index-e.html) mirror. Check in the 2d plot. Otherwise, try the [2D gnuplot demos](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/)

Comment: I do not understand the question. You want Gnuplot to plot lines based on coordinate pairs, right, but where should the line start from? Could you provide a more concrete example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop in (relatively recent) gnuplot:

```
plot for [i=1:4] "file" u (column(2*i-1)):(column(2*i)) w lp
```

will plot four curves, each based on one of the first four pairs of each line in the file.